Angular Reactive Form - Multiple parsing errors when trying to implement multiple step form
I am trying to implement a multi-step Angular Reactive Form in my project. I am using Angular 19. I sought consultation from a tutorial that was written in Angular 8 though.
I am getting several parse errors. I have created a Stackblitz pen to simulate my project scenario as closely as possible. Feel free to work and edit my stackblitz.
This is the link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-grjgagz8
If you visit the multi-step-form.component.ts under app -> components -> multi-step-form,
you will see that there are errors on lines 62, 64, and 91.
If you hover over the red squibbly on the mentioned lines it shows the errors. I tried a number of things like explicitly mentioning the datatypes, but the errors still persist.
Can you help me get that StackBlitz working and display the multi-step form?
*Please study the code I used in my StackBlitz in totality so that you can understand the approach I tried to adopt. Inside the constants folder of my project structure, I have defined the JSON array for forming the steps of my multi-step form.

hi @JamesP did you see the stackblitz I posted? What exactly are you asking to update?

You say the tutorial uses old Angular version is 8 so just use above link to update it to v19 and it will work better in your project?

hi @JamesP the tutorial I spoke of, is a write-up. Written article. If you want, I can post the link here.

Aside from some issues in your original StackBlitz link such as the incorrect component file name for RecipeMultiStepComponent, the selector name for AppComponent
For errors in Lines 62 & 64:
You can resolve this by specifying the validation based on the validator. From my demo below, I added the validations for minLength, maxLength, etc.
getValidators(formField: any): Validators {
  const fieldValidators: any = Object.keys(formField.validations).map(
    (validator) => {
      if (validator === 'required') {
        return Validators[validator];
      } else if (validator === 'minlength') {
        return Validators.minLength(formField.validations[validator]);
      } else if (validator === 'maxlength') {
        return Validators.maxLength(formField.validations[validator]);
      } else {
        // Validation Not supported
        return null;
      }
    }
  );

  return fieldValidators;
}

For the error in Line 91:
You can perform the null checking for masterForm with this.masterForm && this.masterForm[formIndex]
getValidationMessage(formIndex: any, formFieldName: string): string {
  const formErrors = (this.masterForm && this.masterForm[formIndex])?.get(
    formFieldName
  )?.errors;
  const errorMessages =
    this.currentFormContent[formIndex][formFieldName].errors;
  const validationError =
    formErrors && errorMessages[Object.keys(formErrors)[0]];

  return validationError;
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

hi @YongShun, thanks for replying. From your code, I can see for getValidators, you added else if blocks for other types of validation rules also. That removed the error. And for getValidationMessage you applied null checking by adding a '?' to the masterForm[formIndex] object. That's doing the trick! Thanks a bunch Yong,
